# package.json always pull latest version of a package

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

For a project, I want to *always* pull the latest published version of a package from a private npm registry (Azure DevOps > Artifacts)

To ensure the latest version has been published, I've downloaded the artifacts as a zip file and can confirm it's the latest version.

However, when I pull the package using below syntax in `package.json` I'm getting an outdated version.

```
"my-package": "latest"
```

And

```
"my-package": "*"
```

However, if I pull the package manually via the CLI it works fine:

```
npm i my-package@latest
```

How can I make it work from within `package.json`?

Comment: Do you understand why automatically pulling the latest **major** version of a  package is fundamentally the wrong thing to do?  A change in the major version of a package usually indicates a breaking change in the API that will require a code change from the consuming module to continue to work correctly.  In other words, I strongly advise against this.

Comment: What do you mean 'from within package.json'. How are you installing packages? Is there a `package-lock.json` when you build?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to delete `package-lock.json` and go `npm i`. Now it works as expected.